# Evaluate greatest integer less than or equal to $\int_0^1 10x^{\sin x + \cos x}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the following function :
$$f(x) = 10x^{\sin x + \cos x}$$
I want to find the value of $[\int_0^1 f(x) dx ]$, where [.] represents greatest integer function.
I tried replacing $f(x)$ with $f(1 - x)$ but cannot proceed further.
How can we solve this?

Since the function of $x$ is raised over another function of $x$, it is making quite complicated.

Comment: quite complicated indeed...

Comment: You can approximate it: 4.3284... . I doubt if there is an exact expression using simple typical known functions.

Comment: How to approximate it?

Comment: It would also be fine if i can find its greatest integer function

Comment: Would you describe how this integral arose, please?

Comment: @Aruralreader I don't know, it was a question I found somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $sin(x) + cos(x)$ has range $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2} ]$ for x ∈ R but here x varies from 0 to 1, so its range is $[1, \sqrt{2}]$
$$10x^{\sqrt{2}} ≤ f(x) ≤ 10 x$$
We can conclude from this that :
$$\int_0^1 10 x^{\sqrt{2}} dx ≤ \int_0^1f(x) dx ≤ \int_0^1 10 x dx $$
which implies that
$$4.14 ≤ \int_0^1 f(x) dx ≤ 5$$
And since the function f(x) = 10x just at x = 0  and x = 1, so area under f(x) is never gonna equal to 5.

Hence, we can conclude that $[\int_0^1 f(x) dx ] = 4$

Answer (score 2):

I doubt an exact closed form exists. In view of a good approximation to the integral, we Taylor expand the integrand as following:

\begin{align*} x^{f(x)} &= x^{f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}+f'''(0)\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4)} \\ &= x^{f(0)}(e^{f'(0)x\log(x)}  e^{f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}\log{x}} e^{f'''(0)\frac{x^3}{6}\log{x}})x^{O(x^4)} \\ 
e^{f'(0)x\log(x)} &= 1+f'(0)x\log{(x)}+\frac{1}{2}f'(0)^2x^2\log^2{(x)}\\
&\quad+\frac{1}{6}f'(0)^3x^3\log^3{(x)}+O(x^4 \log^4{x}) \\ 
e^{f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}\log(x)} &= 1+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}\log(x)+O(x^4 \log^2{x})\\
e^{f'''(0)\frac{x^3}{6}\log(x)} &= 1+f'''(0)\frac{x^3}{6}\log(x)+O(x^6 \log^2{x})  
 \end{align*}
From above, we obtain \begin{align*} x^{f(x)} &\approx x^{f(0)}\left(1+f'(0)x\log{(x)}+\frac{1}{2}x^2\log{(x)}\left(f'(0)^2\log{x}+f''(0) \right) \right.\\
&\left. \quad +\frac{1}{6}x^3\log{x}(\log^2{(x)}f'(0)^3+3f''(0)f'(0)\log{(x)} +f'''(0))\right)\end{align*}
For $f(x) = \sin{x}+\cos{x}$, $f(0) = 1$, $f'(0) = 1$, $f''(0)=-1$ and $f'''(0)=-1$ , therefore $$ x^{\sin{x}+\cos{x}} \approx x+x^{2}\log x+\frac{1}{2}x^{3}\left(\log x-1\right)\log x+\frac{1}{6}\log\left(x\right)\left(\left(\log x\right)^{2}-3\log x-1\right)x^{4} $$
This gives us $$ 10 \int_{0}^{1} x^{\sin{x}+\cos{x}} dx \approx \dfrac{155819}{36000} = 4.32830\bar{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using exactly the same approach as @Sam, you can generate as many terms of the series as you want
$$x^{\sin (x)+\cos (x)}=x+L\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{P_n(L)}{(n+1)!} \,x^n\quad \text{where} \quad L=\log(x) $$ with
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(L) \\
 2 & 1 \\
 3 & L-1 \\
 4 & L^2-3 L-1 \\
 5 & L^3-6 L^2-L+1 \\
 6 & L^4-10 L^3+5 L^2+15 L+1 \\
 7 & L^5-15 L^4+25 L^3+60 L^2+L-1 \\
 8 & L^6-21 L^5+70 L^4+140 L^3-119 L^2-63 L-1 \\
 9 & L^7-28 L^6+154 L^5+210 L^4-819 L^3-546 L^2-L+1 \\
 10 & L^8-36 L^7+294 L^6+126 L^5-3129 L^4-1470 L^3+1385 L^2+255 L+1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and use
$$\int_0^1 x^m\,\log^n(x)\,dx=(-1)^n \frac{n!}{(1+m)^{n+1}}$$ Using the terms in the above table, the result is
$$\frac{232885723129794291030575849636639249}{538040682787831602922
   81958400000000}$$ which is in an absolute error of $1.75\times 10^{-7}$.